# Submenus of a Dropdown menu appear when i hover via another dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a submenu that appears when i hover over a menu(say Electronics). I did that but whenever i hover over the next element(here next element is another menu named Home Appliances right next to the Electronics menu), then also the submenus of Electronics menu appears. Anyone knows how to solve this?

HTML Code Here:

```
<div class="header_wrapper">
  <a href="index.php"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div class="search">
  <form method="get" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="account">
  <a href="signup.php">SignUp</a>
  <a href="signin.php">SignIn</a>
  <a href="my_account.php">My Account</a>
  <a href="cart.php">Cart</a>
  <a href="track_order.php">Track Order</a>
</div>

<div class="cat_electronics">
  <elec>Elecronics</elec>
    <div class="elec">
      <a>Mobiles<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <a>Mi</a>
      <a>Realme</a>
      <a>Samsung</a>
      <a>Sony</a>
      <a>Infinix</a>
      <a>Oppo</a>
      <a>Vivo</a>
      <a>Nokia</a>
      <a>Motorola</a>
      <a>Apple</a>
      <a>Lenovo</a>
      <a>honor</a>
      <a>Asus</a>
      <a>Google Pixel</a>
    </div>

    <div class="elec1">
      <a>Mobile Accessories<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <a>Mobile Cases</a>
      <a>Headphones & Headsets</a>
      <a>Power Banks</a>
      <a>Screenguards</a>
      <a>Memory Cards</a>
      <a>Memory Cards</a>
      <a>Memory Cards</a>
      <a>Smart Headphones</a>
      <a>Mobile Cables</a>
      <a>Mobile Chargers</a>
      <a>Mobile Holders</a>
    </div>

    <div class="elec2">
      <a>Laptops<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <a>Gaming Laptops</a>
      <a>Office-Work Laptops</a>
      <a>Mid-Range Laptops</a>
    </div>

    <div class="elec3">
      <a>Desktop PCs<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
      <a>Gaming PCs</a>
      <a>Office PCs</a>
      <a>Workstation PCs</a>
      <a>Budget PCs</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="cat_home_appliances">
  <elec>Home Appliances</elec>
    <div class="home1">
      <a></a>
      <a></a>
      <a></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code here:

```
        body{
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  .header_wrapper{
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  }

  .header_wrapper img{
  padding-left: 50px;

  }

  .search {
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: -110px;
  }

  .search input[type=text]{
  padding: 7px;
  font-size: 17px;
  width: 30%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  }

  .search button{
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 6px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  background: white;
  }

  .search button:hover,input[type=text]:hover{
  color: orangered;
  font-weight: bolder;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  }

  .account{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: -28px;
  }

  .account a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 7px;
  background: white;
  }

  .account a:hover{
  color: orangered;
  font-weight: bolder;
  border: 5px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  }

  .cat_electronics{
  margin-left: 250px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  }

  .cat_electronics elec:hover{
  color: orangered;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
  }

  .elec{
  margin-top: 21px;
  display: none;
  border: 2px solid white;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  }

  .elec a{
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  border-left: 1px;
  border-right: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #888888;
  }

  .elec a:hover,.elec1 a:hover,.elec2 a:hover{
  color: orangered;
  }

  .cat_electronics:hover .elec{
  display: block;
  }

  .cat_home_appliances{
  margin-left: 350px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  }

  .elec1{
  margin-top: -497px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  font-size: 15px;
  }

  .elec1 a,.elec2 a,.elec3 a{
  padding: 8px;
  display: block;
  }

  .elec2{
  margin-top: -395px;
  margin-left: 300px;
  font-size: 15px;
  }

  .elec3{
  margin-left: 300px;
  font-size: 15px;
  }
```

Comment: The first thing I notice about your CSS is the fact that you are using negative margins to move some things off of the page (unless I'm not see all of your code) the second is the fact that you are either using a custom tag or you have misspelled select <elec>Elecronics</elec> I imagine you would like to hover home appliances and see these empty a tags?

Comment: @KJEK-Code yes elec is a custom tag i just used. also when i hover over home appliances submenus of electronics appear which is not acceptable

Comment: I am heading into work right now and ill look over it while i'm on my break and get back to you when I get home.  I can only do some much while on my phone. I will probably need dev tools to debug it. Thank you for the answer mark

Comment: Ok, just looking this over (not using Dev tools so I'm not 100%) your .cat_electronics is in an absolute position which breaks it's out of the nomal flow of the doc. Side note your drop-down menu should be absolute not the "button" and it container. Then you have a few negative margin tops on your .elect1 and .elect2 which could cause them to be pushed up on top of your cat_home_appliances. I'll confirm later today

Comment: Updated my answer to explain why the original code did not work properly.  Hope it helps, let me know if you have anymore questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started on the right track  I stripped out the CSS (so you can see whats going on) changed elect to a button and added a wrapper around your elec1 - elec3

Hope this helps

```css
.cat_electronics, .cat_home_appliances {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.elect-container, .home1 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}

.cat_electronics:hover > .elect-container {
  display: block;
}

.cat_home_appliances:hover > .home1 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_wrapper">
  <a href="index.php"><img src="images/1.jpg"></a>
</div>

<div class="search">
  <form method="get" action="search.php">
    <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search...">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="account">
  <a href="signup.php">SignUp</a>
  <a href="signin.php">SignIn</a>
  <a href="my_account.php">My Account</a>
  <a href="cart.php">Cart</a>
  <a href="track_order.php">Track Order</a>
</div>

<div class="cat_electronics">
  <button>Elecronics</button>
    <div class="elect-container">
      <div class="elec">
        <a>Mobiles<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <a>Mi</a>
        <a>Realme</a>
        <a>Samsung</a>
        <a>Sony</a>
        <a>Infinix</a>
        <a>Oppo</a>
        <a>Vivo</a>
        <a>Nokia</a>
        <a>Motorola</a>
        <a>Apple</a>
        <a>Lenovo</a>
        <a>honor</a>
        <a>Asus</a>
        <a>Google Pixel</a>
      </div>

      <div class="elec1">
        <a>Mobile Accessories<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <a>Mobile Cases</a>
        <a>Headphones & Headsets</a>
        <a>Power Banks</a>
        <a>Screenguards</a>
        <a>Memory Cards</a>
        <a>Memory Cards</a>
        <a>Memory Cards</a>
        <a>Smart Headphones</a>
        <a>Mobile Cables</a>
        <a>Mobile Chargers</a>
        <a>Mobile Holders</a>
      </div>

      <div class="elec2">
        <a>Laptops<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <a>Gaming Laptops</a>
        <a>Office-Work Laptops</a>
        <a>Mid-Range Laptops</a>
      </div>

      <div class="elec3">
        <a>Desktop PCs<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <a>Gaming PCs</a>
        <a>Office PCs</a>
        <a>Workstation PCs</a>
        <a>Budget PCs</a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="cat_home_appliances">
  <button>Home Appliances</button>
    <div class="home1">
      <a>one</a>
      <a>two</a>
      <a>three</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Like I stated earlier in the comments, your cat_electronics div was set to position absolute.  When creating a on hover drop down menu the "button" itself should be static and the menu in which it shows and hides should be position absolute .  The other issue is that you did not hide any sub category other than .elec with display none you simply slid them out of the way using negative margin so elec1 is actually still there and it overlaps your home appliances "button" so the way you had your hover set up (meaning display block anytime your button or any sub category is hovered) made it display whenever you tried to hover Home appliances because technically you are hovering elec1 which would cause the menu to show because it is a subcategory of cat_electronics. (see image below) I hope that makes sense and I hope it helps you when creating future drop downs
[image: elec1 is overlapping your button]

Comment: wow it worked, thnx for the helping hand, now can you tell me why my css doesnot work?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you wore targeting 'elec' instead of 'home1' should be:

```
.cat_home_appliance:hover > home1 {
    display: block;
}
```